# ASP.NET get git last commit tag

Tags: .net, git

I'm building a .NET application, using Git as my version control.

I need to get last commit tag from GIT to provide it in my api

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you referring to the use of Git as version control system or you want to access the tag in your program? What's your business case? What's your code? You need to provide much more information or the question can not be answered.

Comment: What do you mean by 'last commit tag'?

Comment: i need to provide information about API version, so the mobile app will recognize if the api has updated, i need to get this version from repository last commit